# why i cant remove value of to empty string once i have entered any value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

problem lies in this code:

whenever i ented any value into my added input, for exmaple like 15 or any number. im able to remove 5 but not 1, or any first number.

here i will link demo. test acc is autofilled if need.

[https://wemove-ochre.vercel.app/gym/chest/Bench_press_a7864ba8-fe09-4605-b9a3-9e4ea9d3ddfc](https://wemove-ochre.vercel.app/gym/chest/bench_press_a7864ba8-fe09-4605-b9a3-9e4ea9d3ddfc)

thank you for your time and help in advance.

```
const set = {
  id: uuidv4(),
  weight: 0,
  rep: 0,
};
const defaultSets = [
 set,set,set
];

const defaultCardioSets = [set];


  const [sets, setSets] = useState<Set[]>(
    type === "cardio" ? defaultCardioSets : defaultSets
  );
  const [allWeights, setAllWeights] = useState(0);


 function handleAddSet(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSets([...sets, set]);
  }

  function handleUpdatePerformance(
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    id: string
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    if (isNaN(newValue)) return;

    const updatedValue = newValue === 0 ? 0 : newValue;
    const updatedSets = sets.map((set) => {
      if (set.id === id) {
        return { ...set, weight: updatedValue };
      }
      return set;
    });

    setSets(updatedSets);
  }


{sets.map((set, i) => (
          <div key={set.id} className="flex gap-2 items-center justify-between">
            <label className="w-1/4" htmlFor={`set_${i}_metric`}>
              {`Set ${i + 1}`}:{" "}
            </label>
            <input
              id={`set_${i}_metric`}
              type="number"
              className="px-2 py-1 w-1/4 my-2"
              placeholder={exercise.metric}
              value={set.weight === 0 ? "" : set.weight}
              required
              onChange={(e) => handleUpdatePerformance(e, set.id)}
            /> ))}
```

i have tried using input as text and pass default as string. but it wont let me go back to empty string.

Comment: Have you considered what `parseFloat("")` is?

Comment: When you remove the last value, the input value becomes `""`. In your `handleUpdatePerformance`, `parseFloat("")` then returns `NaN`, so then the function return without updating the state.

Answer (score 3):

So when you try to remove your input entirely the e.target.value will be an empty string, when that is parsed to float it will return as NaN which then exits out of the function without ever changing the value

```
const newValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);
if (isNaN(newValue)) return;
```

Instead you can add a condition to check if the new value is an empty string by changing

```
const newValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);
```

to

```
const newValue = e.target.value == "" ? 0 : parseFloat(e.target.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

***Your code at parseFloat("") must be returning the function as it will be returning NAN, making your last character not get updated/removed***

[image: return value]

### You might want to try something like this

```
if(newValue == "") // add your logic
else if (isNaN(newValue)) return;
```

Comment: thank you for taking time looking into it. its solved now